# How to get transaction fees when testing using flow-js-testing

Tags: onflow-cadence

I have a mint tx that is paid which I am testing, and i expect this to be true:

```
usersBalanceAfterMinting == usersBalanceBeforeMinting - costOfMinting - txFee
```

However, when i print out the events from the tx, there is no `feesDeducted` event, and no info in the tx as to what the cost of the tx was...

How do I output the txFee using flow-js-testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start emulator with `--transaction-fees` flag like below:

```
await emulator.start(port, { flags: "--transaction-fees", logging: false });
```

Then you can see `FeesDeducted` events.